# Aligning multiple lines so they run in parallel (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, line, alignment

I have a set of lines (least cost paths from on place to another), which i would like to align where they run in parallel. What QGIS-tool could i use for that?

Ideally, I could define a distance and if two lines are next to each other within that distance they get aligned, otherwise they'd stay the same.

[image: Example image of lines that should be aligned]

Comment: You want to merge them into one line where they are close together? Or should they still remain multiple lines but overlapping exactly?

Comment: i'd like to keep multiple overlapping lines...